# What is the simplest way to type ん in Japanese input mode?

Tags: input-method, japanese

In order to type ん in Japanese input mode I have to type
<kbd>n</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>backspace</kbd>.
On my screen, this sequence of keystrokes produces the following results (which explains why I need to type a backspace at the end):

<kbd>n</kbd>
⇨ n

<kbd>n</kbd><kbd>n</kbd>
⇨ んn

<kbd>n</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>backspace</kbd>
⇨ ん

Now, ん is a pretty common character in Japanese, and it is strange/annoying to have to type three keystrokes for it.  Is it possible to type ん with fewer keystrokes?

Comment: What happens if you type something other than `n` on the second keystroke?

Comment: @NickD: the answer to your question depends on what one types.  If one types `a` on the second keystroke, one gets な (the Japanese hiragana character for "na").  If one types `x`, one gets んx.  If one types `.`, one gets ん。(where the second character is the one for period in Japanese typography).  I thought I had tried all the keys before, but somehow I missed that typing `q` (mnemonic: "quit") after the first `n` produces the desired effect of a single ん.  I think this is probably the answer to my question!  I can't imagine a shorter combination, other than possibly some chord-like number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run `M-x describe-input-method` and it will show you the help for the current input method. This should have everything you need. For example, the help for the `japanese-hiragana` input method includes this information:

```
n'  ん
na  な
ne  ね
ni  に
no  の
nu  ぬ
pa  ぱ
pe  ぺ
```